# echo to stdout and append to file

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have this:

```
echo "all done creating tables" >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
```

but that should only append to the file, not write to stdout.
How can I write to stdout and append to a file in the same bash line?

Comment: It is writing to stdout, which is the file

Comment: hmm ok, I guess you're right.. how can I pipe stdout to the "console" / current TTY also then? you know what I am asking :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this?

```
echo "all done creating tables" | tee -a  "${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}"
```

Comment: yeah that looks like it works - any idea if tee is readily available on pretty much any *nix machine? seems to work on macos.

Comment: Oh yes... I think you will find it everywhere. Under Linux it's part of coreutils

Comment: [`tee`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) is part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: oh crap, I forgot to ask, will this send stderr to both the TTY and the file?

Comment: Yes if you redirect stderr to stdout: `my_command 2>&1 | tee -a my_log`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `tee` command

```
$ echo hi | tee -a foo.txt
hi
$ cat foo.txt
hi
```

Comment: oh crap, I forgot to ask, will this send stderr to both the TTY and the file?

Answer (score 1):

Normally tee is used, however a version using just bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mytee (){
    fn=$1
    shift
    IFS= read -r LINE
    printf '%s\n' "$LINE"
    printf '%s\n' "$LINE" >> "$fn"
}


SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH=/tmp/abc
echo "all done creating tables" | mytee "${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}"
```

Comment: This is a case where doing it in pure `bash` doesn't really help you. You need to fork a new process for the RHS of the pipe anyway, so you may as well run `tee` instead of `bash` in that process.

Comment: This depends on how much logging is going to happen. If this is a lot, an exec > >() will work too but is indeed an extra fork. It all just depends on whether tee is available or not. tee however isn't able to prefix & mangle the data, while you can still do this in bash.

Comment: @chepner thx for improving, but "$fn" for windowsy filenames requires fn="$1" too I recon? :-)

Comment: `fn="$1"` won't hurt, but it isn't necessary; no word-splitting or pathname expansion is performed on the RHS of an assignment.

Comment: @chepner Does if it is an array assignment.

Comment: @123 Interestingly, only in the abbreviated form. With `bar='one two'`, `foo=($bar)` will produce an array with elements, but `foo=([0]=$bar)` will not, I suppose because of the simple assignment inside the compound assignment.